# How to get a return value after clicking a certain element using an eventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, event-listener

[image]

```
// Im trying to make these variables have a string return value of their name using a function, as well as applying certain style changes all at once.

let airClick = document.querySelector('#Air').addEventListener
('click', getUserChoice);
let fireClick = document.querySelector('#Fire').addEventListener
('click', getUserChoice);
let waterClick = document.querySelector('#Water').addEventListener
('click', getUserChoice);

function getUserChoice() {

    function airAfterClick() {
        let air = document.querySelector('#Air')
        air.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif')";
        air.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
        return "air"
    }

    function fireAfterClick() {
        let fire = document.querySelector('#Fire')
        fire.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif')";
        fire.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
        return "fire"
    }

    function waterAfterClick() {
        let water = document.querySelector('#Water')
        water.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://media2.giphy.com/media/kTEpI5N6y0bUA/source.gif')";
        water.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
        return "water"
     }
}
```

So what I'm trying to do here is so that when a user clicks on one of the elements on the player side, certain styles activate, for example changing the air element's background to a gif of a tornado once it's clicked, as well as doing certain other actions, more importantly returning a string value of whatever the element name is. That way I can use it as a return value and then do comparisons with the computer's choice.

However I don't know how to exactly do this, and Im not really sure Im formatting my code correctly. But from what I'm attempting to do in my code is to have multiple functions within a function of getUserChoice which activates any of the functions inside of it once it is clicked.

I just have a couple hangups if im going about this the right way. Or if there's an easier way.

1.) If im doing functions within functions should I use an IF statement that activates the function depending on whats clicked? Is that even possible?

2.) Would it make more sense to do the addEventListener inside of the getUserChoice function instead?

Thank u guys for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you delegate - give the container the id of container, give the elements a class of element and do this

```js
const bgURLs = {
  "Air": "https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif",
  "Fire": "https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif",
  "Water": "https://media2.giphy.com/media/kTEpI5N6y0bUA/source.gif"
};

document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("element")) {
    tgt.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bgURLs[tgt.id] + ')';
    tgt.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
  }
})
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.element>span {
  color: orange
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="Air" class="element"><span>Air</span></div>
  <div id="Fire" class="element"><span>Fire</span></div>
  <div id="Water" class="element"><span>Water</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, this solution worked the best for me! But I still have a couple questions about it, how can I use the return value of what was clicked? For exampe say I wanted to return the string "fire" after the fire element was clicked. Would I have to create a separate variable to store that information?

Comment: Depends on where and for what you want to use it. You can creat a global var like currentElement and set that in the click handler

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not need multiple functions here. You can pass this to the function and refer that inside function.

Please Note: The return value of `addEventListener` is undefined.

Try the following way:

```
let airClick = document.querySelector('#Air').addEventListener('click', function(){getUserChoice(this)});
let fireClick = document.querySelector('#Fire').addEventListener('click', function(){getUserChoice(this)});
let waterClick = document.querySelector('#Water').addEventListener('click', function(){getUserChoice(this)});

function getUserChoice(el) {
  var imageUrl = '';

  if(el.id == 'Air')
    imageUrl = 'https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif';
  if(el.id == 'Fire')
    imageUrl = 'https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif';
  if(el.id == 'Water')
    imageUrl = 'https://media2.giphy.com/media/kTEpI5N6y0bUA/source.gif';
  el.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imageUrl})`;
  el.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems with this solution. First `addEventListener` doesn't return anything and second, the elements' IDs start with an upper case letter.

Comment: If the return value of addEventListener is undefined why do you still have it? I think my version is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Adding only slight modification to your existing code:

```js
// Im trying to make these variables have a string return value of their name using a function, as well as applying certain style changes all at once.

let airClick = document.querySelector('#Air').addEventListener('click', getUserChoice().airAfterClick);
let fireClick = document.querySelector('#Fire').addEventListener('click', getUserChoice().fireAfterClick);
let waterClick = document.querySelector('#Water').addEventListener('click', getUserChoice().waterAfterClick);

function getUserChoice() {

  function airAfterClick() {
    let air = document.querySelector('#Air')
    air.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif')";
    air.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
    return "air"
  }

  function fireAfterClick() {
    let fire = document.querySelector('#Fire')
    fire.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif')";
    fire.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
    return "fire"
  }

  function waterAfterClick() {
    let water = document.querySelector('#Water')
    water.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://media2.giphy.com/media/kTEpI5N6y0bUA/source.gif')";
    water.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
    return "water"
  }

  return {
    airAfterClick,
    fireAfterClick,
    waterAfterClick
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="Air">
<p>
Air
</p>
</button>
<button id="Fire">
<p>
Fire
</p>
</button>
<button id="Water">
<p>
Water
</p>
</button>
```

You need to return the inner functions from the main function `getUserChoice` so that it can be listened to by `click listeners` in the buttons.

Comment: What is the rationale to nest the functions like that instead of making them members

Comment: @mplungjan Yea you're right. I was thinking of the same but couldn't think of any possible advantage. Please let me know if any. Also wanted only to make minimal changes to OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

Better to share the work of a small function.

1. Added a separate object with pictures.
2. When you click on an element, you send the element that `e.target` clicked on and the value is `fire`, `wather` or `air`
3. When processing a click, you call a function that substitutes the background, and then send data to the server.

```js
backgrounds = {
 'air': "url('https://media1.giphy.com/media/RK7pdHVS4N7he/source.gif')",
 'fire': "url('https://i.gifer.com/5NOX.gif')",
 'water': "url('https://media2.giphy.com/media/kTEpI5N6y0bUA/source.gif')"
}

let airClick = document.querySelector('#Air').addEventListener('click', function(e) {getUserChoice(e.target, 'air')});
let fireClick = document.querySelector('#Fire').addEventListener('click', function(e) {getUserChoice(e.target, 'fire')});
let waterClick = document.querySelector('#Water').addEventListener('click', function(e) {getUserChoice(e.target, 'water')});

function getUserChoice(el, type) {

 function setBackground(el, type) {
   el.style.backgroundImage = backgrounds[type];
   // el.firstElementChild.style.opacity = 0.4;
 }

 function sendDataToServer(type) {
  console.log('send ' + type + ' to computer');
 }

 setBackground(el, type);
 sendDataToServer(type);
}
```

```css
.elements{
  display: flex;  
}
.elements div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="elements">
  <div id="Air">Air</div>
  <div id="Fire">Fire</div>
  <div id="Water">Water</div>
</div>
```

Comment: addEventListener does not return anything. Also DRY (Don't repeat yourself) See my answer for a more elegant way of not having to add type everywhere

Comment: PS: I borrowed some of your CSS :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead, what you can do is pass an anonymous function to the event handler, call your method which returns a value and use it as appropriate

```
function airClick()
  {
    var ele = document.getElementById("Air");
    ele.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    var result = getUserChoice(event);

    // result is your return value
  }, false);

  }
```